# How to make Zabbix populate more than a single counter from the result of a single request?

Tags: zabbix

I have a Zabbix 3.4 server and a cluster of Nutanix CE software that also happens to have a pretty rich REST API which happens to provide not just status or inventory, but also performance by a single request. I'd like to make Zabbix track this data in separate counters/entities/elements, whatever they happen to be, potentially with the entities they are logically related (say a disk's used space with a disk). The data is in JSON format, with relative entities represented as objects with properties. Is there any way to make Zabbix aggregate the JSON into its database like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record: the required functionality is called "dependent item", you give it master item of type text/json which should somehow hold the JSON REST API response (in 3.4 it's script only, in 4.0 they added "HTTP Agent" item type that can hold full JSON responses), then you give it a sequence of pre-processing steps starting with "JSON path" preprocessing type that interprets the value of previous step (for the first step, the value of master item) as a JSON structure, then traverses that path down the structure and retrieves the value of that key if it exists. Adding several of these items to one master item solves the requested task.